# Using Google Drive api and running script when user denies authorization

Tags: javascript, api, authorization

I'm using the Google Drive Picker api and it's working fine when the user agrees to allow access to their YouTube account, but is there any way to run a function if the user clicks "cancel" rather than "accept"?  I've searched lots for this but can't find anything about where to catch this action!

Javascript is below, thanks for your help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  // The API developer key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
  var developerKey = '???';

  // The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console.
  var clientId = '???.apps.googleusercontent.com';

  // Scope to use to access user's photos.
  var scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'];
  var pickerApiLoaded = false;
  var oauthToken;

  // Use the API Loader script to load google.picker and gapi.auth.
  function onApiLoad() {
    gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
    gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
  }

  function onAuthApiLoad() {
    window.gapi.auth.authorize(
        {
          'client_id': clientId,
          'scope': scopes.join(' '),
          'immediate': false
        },
        handleAuthResult);
  }

  function onPickerApiLoad() {
    pickerApiLoaded = true;
    createPicker();
  }

  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
      createPicker();
    }
  }

  // Create and render a Picker object for picking user Photos.
  function createPicker() {
    if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
      var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
          addView(google.picker.ViewId.VIDEO_SEARCH).
          addView(google.picker.ViewId.YOUTUBE).
          setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
          setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
          setCallback(pickerCallback).
          build();
      picker.setVisible(true);
    }
  }

  // A simple callback implementation.
  function pickerCallback(data) {
    var url = '';
    if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
      var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
      url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];

      parent.document.getElementById("linkstr").value = url;
      window.parent.savelink();
    }
    else
    {
      window.parent.youtubereload();
    }
  }
</script>
```